# How to emit typescript output files in a flat directory structure

Tags: typescript

I have multiple typescript files in a directory structure that looks like this:

```
| src
|      app-1
|           tsconfig.json
|      app-2
|           tsconfig.json
|      common
|      standalone
|           tsconfig.json
```

I have separate `tsconfig.json` files for each of `standalone`, `app-1`, and `app-2`. Each application (app-*) is built with webpack and the output is a single bundle. The standalone files each correspond to an old-school javascript file that is directly included in a page. The common directory contains files used by multiple apps and standalone files.

How do I create a tsconfig file which generates a **flat directory structure** (say in `js/dist` directory). Currently the output looks like:

```
| js
|     dist
|          common
|                 file-common-1.js
|                 file-common-2.js
|          standalone
|                 file-standalone-1.js
|                 file-standalone-2.js
```

Whereas I would like

```
| js
|     dist
|          file-common-1.js
|          file-common-2.js
|          file-standalone-1.js
|          file-standalone-2.js
```

NOTE: there are many questions showing up on Google asking *the opposite*, but I believe these questions refer to old versions of typescript.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if Typescript can do that but it looks it is outside the scope of Typescript.

You can achieve sort of what you need using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/). Hope it helps.